# What do the parentheses do in: late_prop_samp = (late_shipments["late"] == "Yes").mean()

Tags: python, pandas

does anyone know what the first pair of parentheses do in:

```py
late_prop_samp = (late_shipments["late"] == "Yes").mean()
```

The column "late" has "Yes" and "No", and this line returns the proportion of late shipments in the sample.

Comment: it means to run the equality check first, then take the mean. The equality check will produce a boolean vector, which the mean function then treats as 0s and 1s, so this will find the percentage of late_shipments where 'late' is set to 'Yes'

Comment: They prevent you from trying to call `"Yes".mean()`.

Comment: So ... it is basically the equivalent of (1 + 2) * 3, rather than creating a tuple or anything dtype changing?